# How to get HTML when requesting this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to parse the HTML content using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.thespruce.com/christmas-village-display-ideas-8407777"
page = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

But I only get the following response:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Signal - Not Acceptable
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is it somehow possible to get the page-content using `requests`?

(I need this without using `selenium`)

Comment: Can you try : soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Comment: @ufukyılmaz It won't make a big difference, the result remains the same in this case, where there is nothing, just another parser can't conjure up any content either.

Comment: can you try it without ".prettify()" because I got 2562 lines of html code. And you may need to add "header" to your requests.get(url, header). header depends on your browser.

Comment: @ufukyılmaz Same here, there issue is another one, `.prettify()` will not skip the content, it is a `406 error` indication -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) because it seems the website is trying to recognise it. In case there is no result for that it will provide you a [`406 error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406).

```
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.thespruce.com/christmas-village-display-ideas-8407777"
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```